# Convex hull of convex space curve

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, curves, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $\gamma$ be a smooth closed curve $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. We say that $\gamma$ is *convex* if it lies on the boundary of its convex hull, which we denote by $\mathrm{conv}(\gamma)$.

I know that the convex hull of $\gamma$ is, by definition, the set of all convex combinations of points of $\gamma$. I wonder if any point of the hull can be obtained as the convex combination of just *two* points of the curve.

**Question.** Suppose that $\gamma$ is convex, and let $p \in\mathrm{conv}(\gamma)$. Is it then true that
$$p = \lambda \gamma(t_{1}) + (1- \lambda) \gamma(t_{2}) \quad \text{for some $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$}?$$

I expect the answer to be negative, as the the boundary of $\mathrm{conv}(\gamma)$ may contain a polygon. Is this the only obstruction?

Comment: Is a convex hull of $\gamma$ as set of all convex combinations of its points, or is it the interesection of all convex supersets of $\gamma$ by definition? Not sure whether that always coincides

Comment: @SBF They coincide by [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)).

Comment: Is that true that if $\gamma$ does not belong to a single plane its convex hull has a positive measure in $\Bbb R^3$